# How to figure out modify date of table in HANA

Tags: hana

I need something like (on SQL-Server)

```
select name, modify_date 
from sys.tables
```

on HANA.

For those of you who don't know MS-SQL: I would like to query the timestamp of the last insert.

I would like to know the modify date for column and row tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * FROM SYS.M_TABLE_STATISTICS
```

or more specifically:

```
select "TABLE_NAME", "LAST_MODIFY_TIME" FROM SYS.M_TABLE_STATISTICS order by "LAST_MODIFY_TIME" desc
```